# Connecting Signal QML to C++ (Qt5)

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I would like to change a the color of a rectangle when I click a button. They are both in the main.qml file. I'd like to send a signal to C++ backend to change the color of the rectangle. I can't seem to figure it out from the code given in the documentation

main.qml:
    import QtQuick 2.4
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

```
ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true


    id:root

    signal mysignal()


    Rectangle{
     anchors.left: parent.left
     anchors.top: parent.top
     height : 100
     width : 100
    }

    Button
    {

        id: mybutton
        anchors.right:parent.right
        anchors.top:parent.top
        height: 30
        width: 50
     onClicked:root.mysignal()

    }

}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include<QtDebug>
#include <QQuickView>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void cppSlot() {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  MyClass myClass;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QPushButton *mybutton = engine.findChild("mybutton");

    engine.connect(mybutton, SIGNAL(mySignal()),
                   &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> QPushButton *mybutton = engine.findChild("mybutton");
> ```

First, `QObject::findChild` finds QObjects by **object name**, not id (which is local to a context anyhow). Hence in QML you need something like:

```
objectName: "mybutton"
```

Second, I think you need to perform that `findChild` not on the engine itself, but on its root objects as returned from `QQmlApplicationEngine::rootObjects()`.

```
// assuming there IS a first child
engine.rootObjects().at(0)->findChild<QObject*>("myButton");
```

Third, a `Button` in QML is represented by a type that you don't have available in C++. So you can't just assign the result to a `QPushButton *`, but you need to stick with the generic `QObject *`.

Comment: `QList<QObject*> Object = engine.rootObjects();`


`QPushButton *mybutton =`

`Object.first()->findChild("mybutton");`

This code still gives me an error stating "no matching function call"
I've added the objectName property to the button.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a seperate class and header file and then connect it to the signal in main.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include<QtDebug>
#include <QQuickView>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<myclass.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);



    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().at(0);

    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

    MyClass myClass;

    QObject::connect(window,
                     SIGNAL(mysignal()),
                     &myClass,
                     SLOT(cppSlot())
                     );


    return app.exec();
}
```

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS
#define MYCLASS



#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void cppSlot();

};
#endif // MYCLASS
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include<myclass.h>

void MyClass::cppSlot(){

    qDebug()<<"Trying";
}
```